# How do I make github.com exclude my rebase linecount?

Tags: git, github, line-count

I just rebased my repo, and the line count doubled.

I'd like my line count to remain accurate, so I thought I'd ask here.

I didn't see any other questions with a quick glance at search and I already checked every settings menu I can find on the site.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by line count doubled?

Comment: If your repo is on the github and open, could you please give a link to it?

GitHub doesn't seem to provide a tool to count lines. Do you use some external tool?

Comment: Is it possible you are just getting a different line-ending than the system you are on is expecting?  Otherwise, I don't understand the question.  Did you get *duplicate lines* or *new content* or something else?  What tool is giving you the count you think is off?

Comment: When you click on the repo, then on graphs, there is a list of users that have contributed to the repo, with lines added and lines deleted.

Comment: @mu無 before rebase my repo lines showed as x, after they showed as 2x, same for my lines deleted. (except negative of course)

That is what I mean by doubled.

Comment: Could you please give a link to your github repo? This would help A LOT.

Comment: Don't know exactly how github's line counter works, it might be enough to make sure your rebase didn't leave refs to the old history.

Comment: Hahaha omg the kohsuke thing is golden. 

What is this : https://github.com/kohsuke/github-api/tree/master/src/main/java/org/kohsuke/github

I don't even...

Comment: @NickVolynkin, fine I'll link to the repo.

Comment: https://github.com/VhatAmI is the repo @NickVolynkin and everyone else.

Comment: Well guys or gals, I'm -5 on the question right now, and have 22 hours to declare who gets the bounty. The repo I rebased is entitled OmniChess. Prior to rebase, my line counts were both in the 30k range (Which is still wrong... I still need to figure out how to exclude automated line counts.) If you need further information I'll be more available when I wake up tomorrow.

Comment: @hellyale: do not change your original question to make a different one; create a new one instead.

Comment: @hellyale: please, revert those changes you made to your question. Instead you should create a new separate question, as the original one was answered alreday.

Comment: **Stop changing your question!** Once your question has been answered, **do not change the entire meaning of the question**. It invalidates the answers you've already received here, makes the people that answered looks foolish, and can cost them reputation if their now wrong answers get downvoted. If you now have a different question, **post a new question**. You can always link back to this one for details if you need to do so. If you change it again, I'll flag so that a moderator becomes involved to stop you, which if necessary can mean suspending your account. Once again, please **stop**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you shared your repo I can confirm the problem is not with the line counter but with your repo... You have duplicated commits in the history!

[image]
[image]

Don't know how you ended up like that, but you definitely messed up your history tree. ;-)

### How you may fix it

**Disclaimer**: *execute at your own risk. Please, make sure you understand each of the commands bellow before executing them. Always make a backup of your repo before in case anything goes wrong.*

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard c7993946
git cherry-pick 43630629
git cherry-pick 1c4a6df^..27507cca
git push --force
git push origin :VhatAmI-Alphabranch
git branch -D VhatAmI-Alphabranch
```

Comment: The line counter is absolutely not doing its job, this much is true.  I did not make it, it came stock with the website.

Comment: @hellyale: it seems it is doing its job very well indeed. ;-)

Comment: How would I fix this duplicate commit issue without borking my repo?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's counting what's in the originals of your rebased commits because they're still part of the active history. Do you need to keep the other refs to them?

Comment: @hellyale: updated my answer to show a way that may help you fixing that issue.